# cdc_ether 2-1:2.0 net0: kevent 11 may have been dropped

Tags: arch-linux, ethernet

I have a TP-Link USB 3.0 to Gigabit Ethernet Adapter (UE300) and when I plug it into my Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro running Arch (newly installed) it starts to spit out this error a lot:

```
cdc_ether 2-1:2.0 net0: kevent 11 may have been dropped
```

I have read through a ton of pages and a lot of the Arch wiki and have gotten nowhere.

Thanks in advance